# Adding CSS text to iframe contents using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

I'm building a HTML editor using TinyMCE but the HTML file (before TinyMCE has any effect) has a style element in the head. I'm then using several TinyMCE instances on that page, so of course those CSS rules in there aren't being applied to TinyMCE.

I've managed to dump the CSS into a variable, and I've managed to add a `<style>` element to the iframe with the css inside it, however it doesn't affect the styles of the elements inside the frame at all. EG `h2{color:red;}` has no effect, even though I can see it there using Firebug.

This is the code I'm using to get the stylesheet content:

```
if(editor.styleSheets.length > 0){
 var css = editor.styleSheets[0];
 if(!is_ie){
  css.cssText = '';
  for(var i=0; i<css.cssRules.length; i++){
   css.cssText += '\n' + css.cssRules[i].cssText;
  }
 }
 stylesheet = css.cssText;
}
```

Which works, stylesheet contains a string of CSS rules. However, I can't insert it! Any ideas?

Comment: If the style does show up in firebug I'd say there's something else wrong. Do you have an example page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much simpler code snippet to add a css ruleset to the tinymce editors iframes (assuming ed is your editor instance and css_rule is a variable holding your css code):

```
var iframe_id = ed.id + '_ifr';
with(document.getElementById( iframe_id).contentWindow ){
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName( "head" );
    if ( !h.length )    return;
        var newStyleSheet = document.createElement ( "style" );
        newStyleSheet.type = "text/css";
        h[0].appendChild (newStyleSheet);
        try{
            if ( typeof newStyleSheet.styleSheet !== "undefined" ) {
            newStyleSheet.styleSheet.cssText = css_rule;
        }
        else {
                newStyleSheet.appendChild( document.createTextNode ( css_rule ) );
                newStyleSheet.innerHTML = css_rule;
        }
    }
    catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I tried before but it didn't work, although I think was appending the textnode and such before appending it to the head, maybe that's why. Oh well, I tweaked your code a bit and it works great, thanks :D

Comment: problem here might have been that you should create new dom elements in the scope of the iframes document

Comment: That's essentially the same as my code except that it works in fewer browsers and isn't bundled as a reusable function.

Comment: that's the resaon why i voted on your post; but my approch is easier to read becasue its pretty short

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that will add a style rule to a document in all major browsers:

```
var addCssRule = (function() {
    var addRule;

    if (typeof document.styleSheets != "undefined" && document.styleSheets) {
        addRule = function(selector, rule, doc, el) {
            var sheets = doc.styleSheets, sheet;
            if (sheets && sheets.length) {
                sheet = sheets[sheets.length - 1];
                if (sheet.addRule) {
                    sheet.addRule(selector, rule)
                } else if (typeof sheet.cssText == "string") {
                    sheet.cssText = selector + " {" + rule + "}";
                } else if (sheet.insertRule && sheet.cssRules) {
                    sheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + rule + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        addRule = function(selector, rule, doc, el) {
            el.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(selector + " {" + rule + "}"));
        };
    }

    return function(selector, rule, doc) {
        doc = doc || document;

        var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        if (head && addRule) {
            var styleEl = doc.createElement("style");
            styleEl.type = "text/css";
            styleEl.media = "screen";
            head.appendChild(styleEl);
            addRule(selector, rule, doc, styleEl);
            styleEl = null;
        }
    };
})();

addCssRule("h2", "color:red", document);
```

In the case of TinyMCE's editor document, assuming you have an editor instance stored in a variable called `editor`:

```
addCssRule("h2", "color:red", editor.getDoc());
```